# Problem with drawing of flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to draw a flowchart. But the nodes are getting overlapped. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1 in]{geometry}
\hfuzz=20pt
\vfuzz=20pt
\hbadness=2000
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30 ]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Enter A and B and B`(A contains the bigger string)};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {big sentence: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1] {any condition statement .................};
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1] {again a condition............................................................................};
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec2);
\node (dec3) [decision, below of=dec1] {Another one.................................................................................};
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The nodes are not getting placed serially, they are getting overlapped

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. And make sure, you get rid of those `<br>` that your code is [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192).

Comment: Please read http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the library `positioning` and the syntax `below = of ...`.

You had some error with the references for the node placement.

The figure does not fit on one page, but here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}
\tikzset{%
    ,startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30}
    ,io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=white!30}
    ,process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=white!30}
    ,decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=white!30}
    ,arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.7cm]
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    \node (in1) [io, below = of start] {Enter A and B and B`(A contains the bigger string)};
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
    \node (pro1) [process, below = of in1] {big sentence: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
    \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
    \node (dec1) [decision, below = of pro1] {any condition statement .................};
    \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
    \node (dec2) [decision, below = of dec1] {again a condition...............................\-.............................................};
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec2);
    \node (dec3) [decision, below = of dec2] {Another one......................\-.............................\-..............................};
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- (dec3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on `@LaRiFaRi` answer, however with small differences (to show another possible code):

1. I move `tikzset` in `tikzpicture`
2. common features of node I collect in `every node/.style`
3. instead of fill color `white!30` I use `white` (by the way, what color is `white!30`?)
4. I reduce node distance to 1cm
5. I add option `aspect` to diamond shape for reducing it height
6. and brock "long words" (aaa ..., ....) in shorter words, that TeX will be able to form text in more lines.

   Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper, margin=1 in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm,
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, align=center, minimum height=1cm},
%
 startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm},
        io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                     text width=6cm},
   process/.style = {rectangle, text width=6cm},
  decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.2, text width=6cm},
     arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth}
                        ]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io,below=of start] {Enter A and B and B`(A contains the bigger string)};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\node (pro1) [process,below=of in1] {big sentence: aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa a aaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\node (dec1) [decision,below=of pro1] {any condition statement .................};
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\node (dec2) [decision,below=of dec1] {again a condition ...... ........ ......... ......... .. ..... ..... .. ... ..... ... .... .... .... .... ...};
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec2);
\node (dec3) [decision,below=of dec1] {Another one... ..... ..... .... ... .... ..... .... ... .... .... ...... ... .... ..... .. ...... ...... .....};
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```